# Softmax inside the model

Tags: neural-networks, softmax

In section 6.2.2.3 of http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html, the author says

> "More rarely, softmax functions can be used inside the model itself, if
>   we wish the model to choose between one of n diﬀerent options for some
>   internal variable"

I'm trying to think of an example of when one would want to do this. Can someone give an example (or point to a paper) where softmax is used inside the model?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is both a self-study question and is off topic because it is about programming.

Comment: It's about machine learning (which is on topic). "I'm trying to think of an example" doesn't appear to be clearly a self study question to me.